how do I use the anza-xyz/wallet-adapter with my create-react-app?
currently I have a css/react.js widget made in C:\Users\Keola\Desktop\MyToken-ICOWidget\Project\React-Widget\ico_widget which looks like this: (so far) 
I want to tie in the wallet adapter to the widget I have. I tried asking chat-gpt and it broke my project because the info is dated...
How do I add the newer version of anza-xyz/wallet-adapter into my preexisting project?? like where the hell is a tutorial for this also???
thank you.
P.S. I'm using react.js not react.ts

There's also https://github.com/solana-developers/create-solana-dapp to get a working React app with Wallet Adapter.

Here's the page/connections guide for front end daps https://github.com/anza-xyz/wallet-adapter/blob/master/APP.md
Using JS shouldn't be an issue, just remove the TS typings and you should be good to go.

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-web3/issues/827
what's the actual production-ready fix for this?

haven't faced such an error. Can you try removing node modules, your lock file and using the overrides as suggested https://github.com/anza-xyz/wallet-adapter/pull/949
